# Where can I download specific kernel versions for Debian 11?

Tags: debian, download, kernel

I'd like to download a specific kernel version to compile on a virtual machine but I can't find a place to download it. I’d like to find this version `4.19.249-2` for Debian 11 do you know where I could find this ?

It doesn't really matter if I have to go back on my Debian version a bit as long as it is not too much old.

Comment: If I recall, Debian 11 (Bullseye) earliest kernel version is 5.10.0 - not sure you'll be able to get a 4.x kernel at all for Bullseye

Comment: and if I reversed to debian buster/10 ?

Comment: it's still unlikely that **exact** version is available to install (unless you know for a fact that Debian had such a version of course) - you'll probably have to build the kernel yourself (which *may* even be an option for bullseye, i.e. build the specific version you want)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319) question. Why exactly do you need to downgrade to kernel 4.19.249-2? What do you hope to achieve or solve by doing this?

Comment: as an cybersecurity student I want to try to perform attacks on a version of linux that I know is vulnerable debian as a page https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2022-2588 showing a version of linux vulnerable to the vulnerability I want to present in class. I want to build this kernel on a debian inside a VM and record my tests.

Comment: Have a look here and see if what you need may be here: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=kernel. You might also try something like `sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.19.249-2-amd64` but read up on it, backup your system beforehand just in case, and specify the correct acronym part for the CPU architecture you are running e.g `-amd64`.

Comment: looking for linux-image-4.19.249 didn't lead to anything even on debian buster 10.12, but I think I found it under linux-image-4.19.0-21-amd64